# extract values within a range across an entire dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I am trying to extract specific values within a dataframe. I am attempting this because I want to gather relevant information from an output which I have saved as a dataframe so I can pull the information of interest.

I have created a dataframe that contains residual correlations. I have added a column with item names rather than use row names. I have written a function that returns the column name if the value of the residual correlation is above .15: rescorpair <- apply(res.corr, 1, function(x) paste(colnames(res.corr)[which((x > .15 & x < 1.00) |x < -.15 )], collapse = ", ")) 
res.corr is the dataframe with the residual correlations.
This is helpful because by using the column name and row name I can identify the item pair that is above .15. I would like to create a similar function, but one that returns the value of the correlation rather than the row name.

I have included a reproducible example below, but simplified the example in the following ways. Rather than residual correlations, I just made a dataframe of correlations with a couple items.

Generate dataframe:

```
item1<-c(1,3,2,4,5,5)
item2<-c(2,3,5,4,5,4)
item3<-c(3,2,4,5,4,4)
items<-cbind(item1,item2,item3)
corrdata<-Hmisc::rcorr(items)
corr<-as.data.frame(corrdata$r)
corr$itemn<-c("item1","item2","item3")
```

I changed some things about the function that returns column names to fit the example data (I changed the range of values I wanted selected)

```
itemcorr <- apply(corr, 1, function(x) paste(colnames(corr)[which((x > .6 & x < 1.00) |x < -.6 )], collapse = ", "))
```

I would like the output with the values to look like this: 
item1   item2   item3 
  ""  "0.60737" ""

or this 
item1   item2   item3 
  ""  "0.60737" "0.60737"

This is my first question, so please let me know if I need to add any information or make any edits.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` and expected output

Comment: To further @akrun's point, you can find guidelines on how to create a minimal, reproducible example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added a reproducible example and what I would like my expected output to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar using dplyr by converting the data from wide format into long format then applying the condition.

Here is an example of how to do so;

```
library(dplyr)

# Creating items
item1 <- c(1,3,2,4,5,5)
item2 <- c(2,3,5,4,5,4)
item3 <- c(3,2,4,5,4,4)
items <- cbind(item1, item2, item3)

# Calculating correlation
corrdata <- Hmisc::rcorr(items)

# Creating dataframe from correlation list
corr <- 
  as.data.frame(corrdata$r) %>% # Converting to dataframe
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% # Adding row names
  tidyr::gather(key = "item", value = "value", -rowname) %>% # From wide to long
  filter((value > .6 & value < 1.00) | value < -.6) # Adding condition

apply(corr, 1, paste, collapse = " ") # To paste into character

# [1] "item3 item2 0.6073734" 
# [2] "item2 item3 0.6073734"
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is there a way to do it without having to convert the data from wide to long? This is something I will need to repeat many times when analyzing my data so I am wondering if there is something with fewer steps.

Comment: After working with both solutions, I chose this one because the result is quite easy to work with. It looks a bit longer, but ended up being more efficient. I tried to vote for both, but could not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` row-wise, check if any value is in the range and return the value or return `NA`.

```
apply(corr[-4], 1, function(x) {
   inds <- which(x > 0.6 & x < 1)
   if(length(inds)) x[inds] else NA
})

#  item1   item2   item3 
#     NA 0.60737 0.60737
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a simple solution. I was wondering if you might help with an error I get when translating the code to my actual data which has NA values. I get the error "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". I believe it is because there are missing values in my dataframe. I tried to add  and felse(is.na(inds) before the if statement you had (adding a value for true and then your function for false, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: @HeatherClark I have updated the answer. Can you check the updated answer ?

Comment: This worked, but the result is a nested list now. This is a helpful option, so thank you